# Does Java re-evaluate the entire boolean expression in a for loop header?

Tags: java, performance, for-loop, expression

I'm writing some code to tackle a problem on Project Euler, and as usual I must iterate through a range of numbers. However, part of the game is being as efficient as possible. Let's take this code for example:

```
for (int i = 1; i < Math.pow(10,6);i++){
    //code goes here    
    }
```

For every iteration, does Java recalculate 10^6? So, in other words, is this more efficient?

```
for (int i = 1; i < 1000000;i++){
    //code goes here    
    }
```

Comment: I guess compile time optimization kicks-in here.

Comment: I guess optimisation *doesn't* kick in the first case, since `Math.pow` could have side effects or could even have non-deterministic behaviour. Guess you replaced `1000000` with `Math.random() * 1000000d`. How could that be optimized? Since the classes are loaded at run-time and even core classes could change between compiling and running, it should be impossible for the compiler to determine, if a function is deterministic / always returns the same result.

Comment: PS: you could write `(int) 1e6` in this case. Since that's a constant expression (see [jls-15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)), it should be optimized.

Comment: @fabian For compilation from Java to bytecode, definitely. But it probably wouldn't be hard for the JIT to inline the method call and then figure out that it can be replaced with a constant at the call site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's try it:

```
for (int i=0;i<1000000;i++)
```

> 5046949
>
> 5314307
>
> 4619485
>
> 5045923
>
> 4397800

And with the method call:

```
for (int i=0;i<Math.pow(10,6);i++)
```

> 221661393
>
> 222532742
>
> 239673896
>
> 216985460
>
> 221952869

Hmm, so Java does recalculate the method every time. Figures, since it has no way to tell that the method will return the same value over time.

You could also do:

```
for (int i=0;i<(int)1e6;i++)
```

> 4329548
>
> 4781644
>
> 4614867
>
> 4508642
>
> 4508642

Comment: What about the deviation and median of your results?